# Accessing data for SQL object inner join

Tags: sql, join, sqlobject

I am trying to get this inner join to show output the the title and date. Is only returning the sql object that gives details on object. this is result. I can access num_rows but just gives me int(11) for the number of records, don't know how to access the info in the fields. 
This is the result.
object(mysqli_result)#6 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(11) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Thanks for help.

```
$sql  = "SELECT  title, artist_name"; 
$sql .= " FROM follows";
$sql .= " INNER JOIN artworks";
$sql .= " ON follows.user_id_followed = artworks.artist_id";
$sql .= " AND follows.user_id_follower='12'";

$result_set = $database->query($sql);

echo var_dump($result_set);
```

Comment: I think you are invoking the above from PHP. var_dump will only display the PHP-specific details - see [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). You need to actually process the result set row-by-row to display and/or use it - see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php) for the example from PHP's documentation.

Comment: thx will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

you need a WHERE

```
$sql  = "SELECT  title, artist_name"; 
$sql .= " FROM follows";
$sql .= " INNER JOIN artworks";
$sql .= " ON follows.user_id_followed = artworks.artist_id";
$sql .= " WHERE follows.user_id_follower='12'";
```

You also probably want `LEFT JOIN` not INNER JOIN`